# extjs 4 - clickrepeater disabling bug and datepicker

Tags: javascript, html, css, extjs, datepicker

I have a subclass of the DatePicker class.  In the update() method, I check to see if the currentMonth is equal to the month of the minDate property, and if it is, I disable the prevRepeater:

```
me.prevRepeater.setDisabled(me.minDate && me.activeDate.getMonth() == me.minDate.getMonth());
```

The issue I'm running into is that when I click the prevRepeater to go to the previous month and if that month happens to cause the repeater to get disabled, the prevRepeater ends up firing what seems to be infinite click events, which locks up the datepicker.  The only way I can get out of the page is to refresh.  This is undesired behavior.  Is there some detail I overlooked in the docs to prevent this sort of thing from happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the disableDates config property of extjs datefield? or you can also set min/max dates allowed in the datefield config. Not sure which extjs version you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just overriding the click() method and leaving the method body empty.